# WordPress Custom Comment Field - Validation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom comments template which I am using in WordPress, where users can leave reviews/ratings, etc. What I am trying to do is validate that one of the fields is not empty.

Here is my function:

```
function website_verify_comment_review() {
        if (empty($_POST['review-stars-input'])) {
            wp_die(esc_html__('Error: Please add a rating with your comment.', 'website'));
    }
}
```

I am using the 'pre_comment_on_post' hook in my functions.php, as it seems I cannot add this action anywhere else without it not working.

```
add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'website_verify_comment_review');
```

The problem I am having is that this is also running on normal posts where these custom comment fields do not exist, and so the error is also displaying there.

I need this function to run through the filter, ONLY on my custom post type, but it does not seem to work. In my function above I have tried checking that it is not a single post "!is_singular( 'post' )" but this makes it no longer work on my custom post type too.

Perhaps someone knows whats wrong? And why does this only work when I am adding the action from functions.php?

I have also tried adjusting the add_action priority with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

empty() will return true if the value is null or doesn't exist, so maybe you can test if the value exist AND is empty (juste a thought) :

```
if ( isset( $_POST['review-stars-input'] ) && empty( $_POST['review-stars-input'] ) ) {
// your error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function website_verify_comment_review($post_id) {
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'Your post type here') {
        if (empty($_POST['review-stars-input'])) {
            wp_die(esc_html__('Error: Please add a rating with your comment.', 'website'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.